# Are digital signatures a type of zero-knowledge proof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency

Are the digital signatures used in cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin a type of zero-knowledge proof?

Comment: The aim of digital signature verification is to verify that the signature is created with the corresponding private key of the public key. If you ask, who has it, then you can play the game, challenge a message and ask them to sign, check, 1/2 probability, then ask again,... so yes.

Comment: I've modified your question to make it more precise. Please check.

Comment: Could someone write a good educative answer to this?

Comment: I'm now wondering whether ECDSA signatures would be considered as having "computational indistinguishability" for the purposes of the zero-knowledge simulator test, given that the x-coordinate of the EC point commitment is a field element and not a scalar that is uniformly randomly distributed between zero and the group size of the base point.

Comment: According to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35177/is-using-digital-signatures-to-prove-identity-a-zero-knowledge-proof?rq=1 , the answer is no.